# Node.js: is there a way to catch ICMP Destination Unreachable when sending UDP packet?

Tags: node.js, sockets, udp, icmp

Basically the subj. To check whether an app is running on a LAN node that is listening to a specific UDP port when up I'm sending UDP packets to that port. If the port is closed ICMP Destination Unreachable gets sent to me but the question is whether Node.js have any means to receive/process it?